# SoapUI, temper request data break when value is read from property file

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a groovy script as the first test step inside a test case, part of it looks like:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("SampleTestt#Request").getXml()
log.info holder
```

When SampleTest test step has all element values hardcoded, the request xml can be printed fine.

However if some of the request values is read from a test case property, like the following for example

```
${#TestCase#Id}
```

The the above groovy script through error as:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XMLException: error: Unexpected character encountered : '$'
```

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `context.expand()` to evaluate the properties inside your request and then parse the result to xmlHolder, your code could looks like:

```
// get your request replacing the properties inside by their values
def xmlRequest = context.expand('${SampleTestt#Request}')
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(xmlRequest)
log.info holder.getXml()
```

Note that I use `SampleTestt` as your test step request name, but I think that the last `t` could be a typo... check if it's the correct request name before use the code.

Hope this helps,